# jQuery: How to know when a table row loses focus?

Tags: jquery, focus

In a table row (`<tr>`) there are several input elements.

I need to execute some JavaScript code when the tr loses focus (but not when the user just switches to a different input element in the same tr).

I use jQuery.

How to do it cross-browser?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suppose you're looking for this approach ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dU8sn/), checked in Chr/Ff/IE10):

```
var delayedFn, blurredFrom;
$('tr').on('blur', 'input', function(event) {
    blurredFrom = event.delegateTarget;
    delayedFn = setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('Blurred');
    }, 0);
});
$('tr').on('focus', 'input', function(event) {
    if (blurredFrom === event.delegateTarget) {
        clearTimeout(delayedFn);
    }
});
```

As you see we delay the call to our "true blur handler" (which is the function with `console.log` in this example) with `setTimeout` - and clear this timeout if we see the focus stayed in the same row.

I use delegation here so I won't need to call `closest(tr)` each time. But it has another side-effect here, as the handler will deal correctly with the inputs added to the table dynamically.

Comment: You code produces false alerts when I click inside `<tr>` (or inside a `<select>` inside `<tr>`). That's bad.

Comment: Yes, as the only thing that clears the timeout is the function handling `focus` on `input`. It's trivial to update for `select` and all the other inputs (just replace `input` with `:input` selector); as for clicking on `tr`, it should be processed by another event handler - click (but that may fail if user holds a mouse button long enough; focus is lost but click is yet to fire) or mousedown (but that event will be fired before `blur`).

Comment: BTW, what should happen when a user first clicks inside `<tr>`, then click in another `<tr>` (or whatever he seems useful)?

Comment: But what to do if I have several tables for which different event handlers should be executed? Could you provide a code for this more general case?

Comment: It's only a handler function (send in `setTimeout`) that should be replaced in this case. One approach to generalise this to move the whole code into a jQuery plugin taking a callback function as a param, like in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DRmdd/).